# Difference between summation and integration

Tags: integration, summation

It is well known that if a series $\sum\limits_{k= 0}^\infty a_k$ converges, then $a_k \to 0$.

However, this is not true for integrals. What makes them different? Is it simply that they are "smoother?" Is there a rigorous way to explain this difference?

Comment: Are you saying that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\text{conv.}\not\Longrightarrow f(\infty)=0$ ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that this is, in fact, incorrect.

Comment: Could you give a simple example ?

Comment: See my response to one of the posts below :). Sadly, the examples aren't too simple.

Comment: The discrete sum is like an integral of rectangles, whose width is always $1$, and whose height is $f[k]$, so its area is dependent upon the height *alone*: If the latter does not tend to $0$, the sum/integral cannot converge either. But in the case of an actual integral, each such area is not *necessarily* a rectangle, therefore it can be manipulated towards $0$ without *necessarily* having to let the height tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a non-negative function $f(x)$ whose graph is spiky in a very specific way. Around each positive integer $n,$ let the graph be an isosceles triangle with the tip being $f(n) = 1,$ and the base have width $1/2^n.$ Take the integral of $f$ out to infinity. The contribution of each spike is $1/2^{n+1},$ that being the area of the isosceles triangle. I think the entire integral is $1/2$ because the triangle around 1 starts with area $1/4.$

It's not smoothness. It's that there is width as well as height.

Comment: The example I'm familiar with: If $g(x) = 1 - |x|$ for $x \in [0, 1]$ and 0 elsewhere, and $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}g(k^2[x - k])$, then the integral of $f(x)$ over $[0, \infty)$ is $\pi^2/6 - 1$. However $f(x)$ does not tend to zero, as it is equal to 1 for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ayesha, if you want, you can have the height of the spike $n,$ while the base of the spike is still $1/2^n.$ Still convergent integral, even though the spikes are getting taller.

Answer (score 1):

With integration each input contributes much more negligibly compared to summation. Thus naturally, you will learn less about the tail of the function from the integral than the tail of the sequence from the sum. Note that you can turn an improper integral into an infinite sum by breaking it into integrals over even length intervals. But its the AVERAGE value of the function over each interval that is put into the sum (saying length of each interval is 1), thus information is lost.

Comment: (Note part doesn't always work for establishing convergence, but I think it is illustrative)