# Difference between integral and summation.

Tags: calculus

Well I am not a  math expert as most people are on this site but I feltb this site would help me.
$$\int_0^n x dx = \frac{n^2}{2}$$
also
$$\sum_{x=0}^{n} x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
(it is suggested that it may also be written as)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0}^n x \triangle x
$$
What are we doing in the above two.Both sum up so in this case if $$n>0$$ why is $$\int<\sum$$?
I have read [Difference between summation and integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635351/difference-between-summation-and-integration) but still it is not clear to me why integration is less than summation in this case for natural numbers.

Comment: The integration is done from 0 to n.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#:~:text=Loosely%20speaking%2C%20the%20Riemann%20integral,more%20specifically%20Riemann%2Dintegrable) .It may be helpful.

Comment: Isn't your summation valid from 0 to n...

Comment: Well everyone below successfully answered t

Comment: Thanks I understood.

Comment: Yeah changed it.

Comment: From 0 to n now.

Comment: From 0 to n that is not the summation formula correct or am I wrong?

Comment: If we sum from 0 or one result will be same.

Comment: It is up to n integer not n terms.

Comment: Also I could suggest you rewrite the integral as a summation as follows: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{0}^n x \triangle x$

Comment: But not for x+1, or anything with constant, because integrals take those into considerations as well but I see you have part of the scope

Comment: There is a significant application of the calculus of finite differences in developing summation formulae (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation as an introduction).  I remember some challenging homework problems in my finite difference theory course.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture of the area under the parabola between $x=0$ and $x=n$ and superimpose rectangles with unit base corresponding to the terms in the sum. You will see the inequality.

Here is what it looks like (with intervals shorter that $1$).

Whenever the function you are integrating is increasing, this sum will overestimate the integral.

The corresponding sum using the left endpoints of the subdivision will reverse the inequality.

[image]

Source:
https://web.northeastern.edu/dummit/teaching_fa19_1341/calc1_4_introduction_to_integration_v2.00.pdf

Comment: I am again a bit new to calculus but I asked on this site.Can you once tell that when we are integrating we are taking every infinitesimally small bit but in summation we take discrete values but still sum is more than integral how?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The red line ist your function f(x) = x, in the sum, you essentially compute the area of the rectangles and add them up, thats why the integral is smaller.

Comment: Well "question" just answered to "ask".

Answer (score 0):

Here a picture, in red we see the sum as described above. And the blue area is the integral analogue.

[image: Example image]